# I am working on django but my static files are not loading

Tags: python, django

These are my files kindly tell me what i am doing wrong or what changes are needed to be done

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
```

index.html

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 
'firstapp/style.css' %}"/>
    <h1>Here are all Albums</h1>
    {% if all_albums %}

        <ul>
            {% for album in all_albums %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'firstapp:detail' album.id %}">{{ album.album_title }}</a> </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% else %}
        <h1>No data found</h1>
    {% endif %}
```

style.css

```
body{
    background: white url{"images/background.png"};
}
```

mysite/firstapp/urls.py

```
app_name = 'firstapp'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<album_id>[0-9]+)/$',views.detail, name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<album_id>[0-9]+)/favorite/$', views.favorite, name='favorite'),
]
```

mysite/mysite/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^firstapp/', include('firstapp.urls')),
]
```

[This is the file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mU7CK.png)

Comment: what is the folder structure?

Comment: show your core urls.py

Comment: urlpatterns = [
    url('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^firstapp/', include('firstapp.urls')),
]

Comment: app_name = 'firstapp'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<album_id>[0-9]+)/$',views.detail, name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<album_id>[0-9]+)/favorite/$', views.favorite, name='favorite'),
]

Comment: Is this on production or using the dev server, and in the later case, did you add `django.contrib.staticfiles` to your `settings.INSTALLED_APPS` as documented here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/ ?

Comment: yes django.contrib.staticfiles is added settings.INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: does `style.css` is loading?

Comment: no style.css is not loading

Comment: is `DEBUG=True`?

Comment: yes DEBUG = TRUE